# How do I set arguments for preparedStatement in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, arguments, prepared-statement

I'm calling from another class for this function which does the setting of the arguments into a prepared Statement according to their data types. I have a rough idea of how it is to be done, but I can't seem to get it right.
How do I use the function to set the parameters into the sql statement via prepared statements?

Comment: The number of `?` must exactly match the number of argument.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik I 'm trying to use the CalledFunc to set the variables "string1", "string2", 1 into the sql statement via prepared statements

Comment: Please add a description of the problem you have, and any errors you get. Just posting _"but I can't seem to get it right"_ is not very helpful and does not help us determine what we need to focus on in answering your question. That said your nested loop is curious to say the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use my approach:

```
if (arguments[i] instanceof String){
    //set the strings into the varchar2 fields
    preparedStmt.setString(i+1, arguments[i].toString());
}
else if (arguments[i] instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println("Integer " + i);
        //set the integers into the integer fields
    preparedStmt.setInt(i+1, Integer.parseInt(arguments[i].toString()));
}
```